# Getting start with Jongo

Tags: mongodb, jackson, bson, jongo

I'm trying to run an "hello world" with Jongo

I added the jar  manually (not with Maven)

This is the code I ran:

```
public  class Friend {  
    @Id 
    private String myId;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "mydb.mongohq.com", 10014 );
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "db-name" );
        Jongo jongo = new Jongo(db);
        MongoCollection friends = jongo.getCollection("collection");
        Friend joe = new Friend();
        friends.save(joe);
}
```

And I'm getting this mistake:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at org.bson.io.PoolOutputBuffer.write(PoolOutputBuffer.java:74)
    at org.bson.LazyBSONObject.pipe(LazyBSONObject.java:451)
    at org.jongo.bson.BsonDBEncoder.writeObject(BsonDBEncoder.java:39)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:239)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:204)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:148)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:91)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:810)
    at org.jongo.Insert.save(Insert.java:55)
    at org.jongo.MongoCollection.save(MongoCollection.java:128)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have added the jar dependencies — Jackson 2.1, Bson4Jackson 2.1 and Mongo Java Driver 2.9+ — it seems to me that your Friend class de not have a private constructor. [The mapping section of the documentation](http://jongo.org/#mapping) explain this in details.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was using Jackson 2.2.1 and not 2.1,
after changing it to 2.1 it is working great.